# VB textbox.enter gives null value (accumulator)

Tags: vb.net, controls, enter

Have I simple VB program which accumulating via TextBox.Enter fails. Goal is: how fix TextBox.Enter? I do not get MsgBox, indicating that action tree has not been followed.

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class MainForm

Public decexpenses, decincome As Decimal
Public dectotalexpenses As Decimal = 0
Public dectotalincome As Decimal = 0

Private Sub MainForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox("Use Enter key to enter values.")
End Sub

Private Sub expensesTextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles expensesTextBox.Enter
    Do Until expensesTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        Dim expenses = expensesTextBox.Text
        MsgBox(expenses) ' i dont get a msgbox for this indicating this value is null
        Do Until IsNumeric(expenses)
            MsgBox("Please enter numeric value for expenses.")
        Loop
        decexpenses = CDec(expenses)
        dectotalexpenses = decexpenses + dectotalexpenses
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub incomeTextBox_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles incomeTextBox.Enter
    Do Until incomeTextBox.Text = String.Empty
        Dim income = incomeTextBox.Text
        Do Until IsNumeric(income)
            MsgBox("Please enter numeric value for income.")
        Loop
        decincome = CDec(income)
        dectotalincome = decincome + dectotalexpenses
    Loop
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: In most cases when the user goes to/activates/enters the TextBox the contents are empty so the outer `Do Until` condition is already met and nothing happens. Good thing, because the inner `Do Until` is an infinite blizzard of MsgBoxes

Comment: You are doing validation before they entered anything.  Validate in the Leave event or use the Validating event.  You cant use a loop like that in an event - you have to exit the event so they can enter/correct the input

Comment: I looked up validation event, I had not heard of this before, thanks, but where / how does it affect this code?

Comment: Are you trying to use "Enter" to see if the Enter key was pressed?  The Enter event is for when the cursor has been placed in the textbox.  Are you looking for the KeyDown event, to look for where e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter?

Comment: @Capellan  good interpretation!  I wondered why anyone would think that event was appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you just right a method that does the below? It appears that all your looking is to check to make sure it is an integer that was entered into the textbox and if it is calculate it, otherwise display a messagebox to tell the user to enter a number.

```
 Private Sub expensesTextBox_Enter(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles expensesTextBox.KeyPress
    Dim dectotalexpenses As Decimal = 0
    Dim dectotalincome As Decimal = 0

    Dim income As String = expensesTextBox.Text

    If Keys.E + Keys.Enter Then


        If IsNumeric(income) = True Then
            dectotalincome = income + dectotalexpenses

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Number")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```